# Host an Ionic app into AWS S3 Bucket - Not working/rendering

Tags: angular, redirect, ionic-framework, amazon-s3, routes

I have created a simple app using ionic2 framework and is working well in local machine/behind a simple 'lite-server'

I wanted to deploy the same in AWS S3 - With "**enable static web-hosting**" and try it from mobile browsers

I ran - `ionic build browser`

This created a static web-page contents in \MyApp\platforms\browser\www.

I used a node tool 's3-website' - https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-website

to publish my App content to S3

All went well, I enabled static web-hosting, had permission for everyone to view, but its not rendering.

**Edited**
Should the app module name "MyApp" and s3 bucket name match? curious?

In Chrome Console, I get these errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/build/main.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
device.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
statusbar.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
StatusBarProxy.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
SplashScreenProxy.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
splashscreen.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
DeviceProxy.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
keyboard.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cordova.js:1297 Uncaught Error: Module cordova-plugin-device.device does not exist.
    at addEntry (cordova.js:1297)
    at Object.exports.clobbers (cordova.js:1307)
    at onScriptLoadingComplete (cordova.js:1551)
    at HTMLScriptElement.scriptLoadedCallback (cordova.js:1584)
addEntry @ cordova.js:1297
exports.clobbers @ cordova.js:1307
onScriptLoadingComplete @ cordova.js:1551
scriptLoadedCallback @ cordova.js:1584
cordova.js:1582 [Violation] 'error' handler took 177ms
main.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cordova.js:1051 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1044 Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
cordova.js:1044 Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your files are copied there. If possible, install AWS CLI and clear your existing files in the bucket. Now, try aws s3 cp  s3:/// --recursive. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either files are missing or the folder structure is incorrect. Did you test the site from your local machine?  Create a folder and download/copy the entire website content to the local folder.  Now launch index.html and see what happens.